# How do i train my dataset, having 100.000 elements and 2 features

Tags: tensorflow, google-colaboratory

I am trying to do a review classification on the amazon review dataset using neural networks but every time i try to run it on google colab it shows OOM error, which I understand is due to memory overflow. But can anyone tell how should I train my dataset.

P.S.- Even taking small batches didn't work.

Comment: Are we talking about the number of features or the number of elements/items in the dataset?

Comment: These are the *elements to train in dataset.With 2 different features.

Comment: I want to help you, but I need some code in order to do so; I cannot help you if I do not see code.